# Is okapi pipeline instance thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, translation

I'm planning to build a service which uses okapi pipeline as the core library for translation. And for this I plan to have a singleton instance of the pipeline. However based on the code which I went through, most of the classes are stateful (like regex plain text filters), making the pipeline not thread safe. Is there any way we can have a singleton of the okapi pipeline instance?
Did anyone face a similar situation while developing using okapi libraries?

Answer (score 0):

None of the filters are threadsafe, and I am fairly sure a lot of the pipeline code isn't either.  Other people have run into this problem as well, but it's never been fixed -- the amount of code required (particularly to change the filters) is quite large.  A general workaround is to abstract the filtering/pipeline process away behind something that looks threadsafe from the outside, such as [Longhorn](https://okapiframework.org/wiki/index.php?title=Longhorn) (or [MateCat-Filters](https://github.com/matecat/MateCat-Filters)).